# blackberry webpage image scale issue

Tags: html, css, mobile, blackberry, web

on the following webpage, all images are set to have a maximum width of 100%. This works fine on all devices except for blackberrys. Has anyone come accross this issue?

http://www.applewoodindependent.co.uk/

Comment: have you set the right screen size in the media query? Blackberries are all dif screen sizes im guessing so hard to narrow down to one model like you can with the iPhone.

Comment: it isnt set in a media query, it should be the same no matter which screen size..]

Answer (score 0):

In Blackberry as we don't have the webview like in iOS or android.....we have the browserfield2 api.

In the browserfield2 you can scale the web page using the initiale scale method in the browser field config.

```
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.INITIAL_SCALE, new Float(value));
```

Adjust the scaling by passing the correct value in the method.